# Are (Firefox add-on SDK) page-workers Twitter-incompatible?

Tags: firefox, twitter, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

When I create page-workers for pages in the `twitter.com` domain, nothing happens.

`lib/main.js`:

```
var pw = require("sdk/page-worker");

pw.Page({
  contentScript: "console.log(window.location.href)",
  contentURL: "https://google.com"
});

pw.Page({
  contentScript: "console.log(window.location.href)",
  contentURL: "https://twitter.com"
});
```

Console output is as follows:

```
console.log: twitter-worker: https://www.google.com/
```

That's all, folks.  I haven't yet gotten a content script to run for any page-worker using any Twitter URL is its `contentURL`.  Is this some kind of trick to get us to use Twitter's API?

Comment: They definitely aren't incompatible with twitter, twitter just might be doing something different so you just have to figure out how it works. Like I recently had to figure out how page loading on youtube worked when clicking links to make an addon there, I suspect something similar with twitter.

Comment: So far I've figured out that the problem seems to be a Content Security Policy.

Comment: Thanks for sharing please post solution below I'm curious

Comment: A solution is one thing I don't have.  I did overcome "nothing happens" by setting `contentScriptWhen` to `"ready"`.  Also changed the content script for the Twitter page-worker to:

`console.log(document.body.outerHTML)`

The output from this is an HTML page apparently generated by Firefox.

http://pastebin.com/rWNcN2W2

Comment: This is the value of the `content-security-policy` header from twitter.com: `"default-src https:; connect-src https:; font-src https: data:; frame-src https: twitter:; frame-ancestors https:; img-src https: data:; media-src https:; object-src https:; script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https:; style-src 'unsafe-inline' https:; report-uri https://twitter.com/i/csp_report?a=NVQWGYLXFVZXO2LGOQ%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D%3D&ro=false;"`

Comment: Hi Lori, I had a project where I hit this same thing and I resolved it earlier, I forgot to share the solution, I used evalInSandbox - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32013468/1828637

Comment: This topic links an article to MDN which gives the code that worked exactly for me on Twitter - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32495180/1828637 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Example