# Content Scripts: Page-worker - <body> element with 0 width

Tags: javascript, css, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I want to automatically open a website and reveal details about the rendered DOM. For that purpose I use a page-worker (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-worker). When in the content script I execute something like the following:

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
console.log(getComputedStyle(body).width);
console.log(body.getBoundingClientRect().width);
```

The output is "0" for both of the width values. The same also applies to other elements. Should I conclude that DOM elements are not rendered properly when using a page-worker? Is there a way to gain authentic data from that? Or is there any other proper way to get details about the rendered DOM that behave exactly like the website was opened in a web browser by hand? Because if I open the same website manually and execute the same commands, it reveals (correctly) the width of the window (1440), of course.

**edit**
I probably should have said that before, but:
It's not that gaining the values does not work at all. If I go deeper in the DOM structure, I get correct values. I only have problems with the root body element, I think. Weirdly enough if I execute the exact same commands on the firefox console, the return values are perfectly correct.

Comment: Have you made sure the website you're trying to open with a page-worker does not have a Content Security Policy?  I ran into this, with no apparent way out...

http://stackoverflow.com/q/27085661/948073

Comment: Yes, because the values are legit for some elements deeper in the dom tree. Sorry, I should have written that.

Answer (score 1):

It's very interesting the way you do it.

1. You don't have to do `getElementsByTagName` to get the body element, its a property of the `document` object `var body = document.body;`
2. `getComputedStyle` is a function of the `window` object so that's why it works without you putting `window.` in front of it but still just want to let you know.
3. You dont do a `getPropertyValue` which is required for `getComputedStyle`, I just tried it without it and it worked but i never saw it used like that before so maybe that has something to do with it:

So doing this from bootstrap or from scratchpad window: `gBrowser.contentWindow.getComputedStyle(gBrowser.contentDocument.body).getPropertyValue('width')`

works for me.

From your content-script scope do:

```
window.getComputedStyle(document.body).getPropertyValue('width')
```

If it still doesn't work I would thinky maybe myabe maybe, thers a chance you might be executing the code to early.
Let me know how that works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In fact for some elements there are legit values for width, height etc. So I do not assume that it does not work at all. It just fails for the root element of the body. It is also not executed too late, because if not specified the content scritps are executed when the dom and external resources are loaded.