# How to inject script when contentaccessible=yes fails

Tags: firefox-addon

I have to listen to a jquery event in a webpage. I can't attach a function from wrappedJSObject, becuase it has issues executing functions created in chrome scope.

So I thought to dynamically insert a script, which will dispatch a custom event, which I will my addon listen for. But here's simple case, with just inserting script that alerts:

```
var aContentWindow = gBrowser.contentWindow;
var aContentDocument = aContentWindow.document;

var myScript = aContentDocument.createElement('script');
myScript.textContent = 'alert("registered");'

aContentDocument.documentElement.appendChild(myScript);
```

So the site I am trying to run this on is twitter, it works on other sites.

So I figured lets do this from addon scope with chrome path which had `contentaccessible=true` so I did that, but it would still give me the error:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-hnhqgKrLIxRgkHGdVqfgfA==' 'unsafe-eval' https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://platform.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://analytics.twitter.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://api.twitter.com https://graph.facebook.com https://www.google.com"). twitter.com:562:0

and a second one too at same time:

> Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at self ("script-src 'unsafe-inline' 'nonce-hnhqgKrLIxRgkHGdVqfgfA==' 'unsafe-eval' https://twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://platform.twitter.com https://syndication.twitter.com https://analytics.twitter.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://ssl.google-analytics.com https://connect.facebook.net https://cm.g.doubleclick.net https://api.twitter.com https://graph.facebook.com https://www.google.com").

Any ideas how to get this script in there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the [subscript loader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/mozIJSSubScriptLoader), with the wrappedJSObject as target context, instead of manipulating the DOM?

---

Another thing you could try is creating [a sandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox), specify the target window as `sandboxPrototype`, set `wantXrays` to `false` and use the target window's `document.domain` as security principal.

That should give you a sandbox with full access to the target window that shouldn't throw any security errors because it will use [transparent wrappers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Gecko/Script_security#Same-origin).

Once you have that sandbox you can try running your script inside the sandbox via [evalInSandbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.evalInSandbox) or using the subscript loader with the sandbox as target instead of the window.

Comment: I tested this but couldn't get it to work, any other ideas? :(

Comment: Thanks so much man! I really want to try that some day soon it's something I never explored!