# Firefox Addon Issue with loading custom font on Github

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon for firefox using the Addon SDK. In my css file, I have a font in the Data URI format. On stackoverflow, twitter, gmail it is loaded correctly, however, on Github, I get the error `Content Security Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource` any ideas as to why? Its not an `http vs https` issue either, as I tested it out with both protocols. I would deeply appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: github CSP is `font-src assets-cdn.github.com`. Evidently this does not include `'self'`. It seems to me you may be out of luck here

Comment: I had same issue on Twitter I think, please try it out - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32013236/how-to-inject-script-when-contentaccessible-yes-fails?s=3|0.0000

Comment: This topic links an article to MDN which gives the code that worked exactly for me on Twitter - http://stackoverflow.com/a/32495180/1828637 - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_Bindings/Components.utils.Sandbox#Example